# .htaccess redirect specific query string to the home page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've looked for this in various forums but couldn't find one that resolves this specific issue.

I need to redirect a specific query string "www.example.com?cat=1 (or any other number) to "www.example.com".

I tried this method in .htaccess but it didn't work.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^cat=$
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.example.com  [R=301,L]
```

Could anyone please enlighten me as to what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=.+$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /? [L,R]
```

The reason why your redirect failed is because **^cat=$** matches **/?cat=** without the number perameter. To fix this, I have added a catch-all **.+** pattern which matches any chars in the query value.

Comment: Mate, you are a legend!